# How to change the SelectMethod of ObjectDataSource programatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

Suppose I have a given ObjectDataSource, this objectdatasource "SelectMethod" property is set to "GetProjectsByUsername" of a class Project and accepting one parameter.

```
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="GetProjectsDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetProjectsByUsername"
    TypeName="BusinessLayer.Project">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hiddenUsername" Name="username" PropertyName="Value"
            Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Now, Is it possible to change the SelectMethod property of this ObjectDataSource to a method that accepts two parameters during OnInit method? for example

MethodName :  GetProjectByUsernameDeptCd()
Parameters : Username , DepartmentCode

I would like to change the select method by User Roles. I've tried to search SO and Internet but it seems that I have no luck on it. Anyway I wanted to do like:

> if ( Role is Admin )
>          Use the default SelectMethod and Parameters that is declared in ASPX
>     else
>          Change the SelectMethod to "GetProjectByUsernameDeptCd"
>           Set parameter1 = value1
>          Set parameter2 = value2

Or I was thinking if there are other better ways to do this.

Thank You and Best Regards,
Sherwin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 GetProjectsDataSource.SelectMethod = "GetProjectByUsernameDeptCd";
 Parameter p1 = new Parameter("parameter1 ",TypeCode.String);
 Parameter p2 = new Parameter("parameter2 ",TypeCode.String);
 GetProjectsDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(p1);
 GetProjectsDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(p2);
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I will try this one. This one should be also done in OnInit of the page class right?

Comment: Hey thanks, can't believe this is so easy. >.< I was thinking of invoking delegates lol.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do this in the **OnSelecting** event of the ObjectDataSource in a code-behind file.

Ex.

```
protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        ObjectDataSource1.SelectMethod = "<YourSelectMethod>";
        e.InputParameters.Clear(); // this is a different method with new parameters.
        e.InputParameters.Add("Param1", "Value1");
        e.InputParameters.Add("Param2", "Value2");
        e.InputParameters.Add("Param3", "Value3");
    }
```

For more details please read below articles :
1. http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/pages/426642.aspx

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selecting%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
2. http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/programmatically-setting-the-objectdatasource-s-parameter-values-vb

Hope this will help..

Happy Programming!

Comment: Hi thanks, but I think changing the ObjectDataSource property in OnInit method is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the C# codebehind? Instead of defining it in the aspx markup, go to the codebehind file, and do it there.

Comment: Well, basically I was asking on how to this in codebehind. :)